# Jacobian matrix negative sign when transforming variables for integrating over plane?

Tags: transformation, surface-integrals, jacobian

Hi I'm trying to integrate a function $e^{f(x,y)}$ over a x-y plane and I have some transforming variables : 
$$
u=x-y
$$
$$ 
v=x+y
$$
now the determinant of the jacobian matrix would be positive since
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        u \\
        v \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 &  1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is the matrix. Therefore if I were to integrate over the u-v plane, I get positive values(as I expected). But the problem rises when I instead write
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        v \\
        u \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 &  -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
now the determinant is negative. Since it's the exponential form function that I am integrating, it should give me a positive value but for this case it gives me a negative value. Now I know that somewhere 'flipping' has occurred, but how do I distinguish which one to use, $$
\begin{pmatrix}
        u \\
        v \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 &  1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        v \\
        u \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 &  1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ ??

Should I just always use the definite value of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix? Please help, thanks:)

Comment: The change of variables formula is that $$\int_{\varphi(U)}  f(v) \, dv = \int_U f(\varphi(u)) |\det D\varphi(u)| \, du$$ which has an absolute value in it.

Comment: The sign of the determinant tells you the difference in orientation of the bases of the cotangent space that are used in the old and new integral (which is why it swaps sign when two columns are swapped). Since you don't care about this information, you take the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @user296602@Chappers